# Set Proxy on WebView for API 26

Tags: java, android, android-webview

firstly
I have read all the answers written about questions similar to my question. But none of the solutions helped me.

this is my Webview Code

```
mWebView.loadUrl(siteUrl);       
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);      
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);      
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new mWebViewClient());
```

i tried to use this class
https://gist.github.com/madeye/2297083

And I used this code to set proxy

```
ProxySettings.setProxy(getApplicationContext(), "x.x.x.x", 8080);
```

I also tested this class
https://gist.github.com/WanghongLin/50032a4d3933960454a7

and

```
WebViewHttpProxy.setProxy(mWebView,"x.x.x.x",8080);
```

But none of them worked. and proxy was not applied when i ran the app

Answer (score 1):

Very easy set proxy on your android webview app ✅

compile 'androidx.webkit:webkit:1.3.0'
setProxy(); just load before your webview Url loading .

```
private void init() {
    wv = findViewById(R.id.wv);
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm){
            
            handler.proceed("userName", "password");
        }
    });
    setProxy();
    wv.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");
}

private void setProxy() {
        ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig.Builder()
                .addProxyRule("123.123.123.123:1234")
                .addDirect().build();
        ProxyController.getInstance().setProxyOverride(proxyConfig, new Executor() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Runnable command) {
                //do nothing
            }
        }, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                
            }
        });
    }
```

Enjoy

Comment: anyone tried it ? will it work ?

Comment: not working for me

Comment: new ProxyConfig.Builder()
                .addProxyRule("123.123.123.123:1234")
Proxy rule should have the scheme, for example, HTTP proxy should have                 .addProxyRule("http://myproxy:80")

Comment: Not Working. Testing on A11

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I feel you're setting the proxy after loading the url (`webView.loadUrl`) so it may not apply